# Atualizar referência de web service ASMX dinamicamente

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, referência

Eu tenho uma aplicação C# que consume um webservice **asmx** (que também é desenvolvido em C#).

Sempre que eu publico uma nova versão do webservice, eu preciso atualizar a referência (do webservice) nas aplicações que o consomem. A operação de atualização é apenas clicar com o botão direito em cima da referência e clicar em **Update Web Reference**, como mostro na imagem abaixo:

[image: Solution Explorer -> Web References]

Existe alguma forma fazer isso via código?

Comment: O menu de "Update Web Reference" usa o mesmo código que a ferramenta [`wsdl.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/7h3ystb6). Talvez não via código (C#), mas você pode usá-la em um projeto do MSBuild, ou via command-line (.cmd, .bat) para atualizar o arquivo da referência...

Comment: Acho que não entendi a sua necessidade. Quando você atualiza a referência do Web Service ele altera o seu proxy, o que pode te gerar erros de compilação na aplicação. Qual a vantagem de automatizar isso se tem grandes chances de você precisar alterar a sua aplicação?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nos seguintes links, e veja se te ajuda: [MSDN](http://forums.asp.net/t/1422801.aspx?How%20to%20automatically%20update%20web%20reference%20in%20client%20application) [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159599/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-web-reference-at-build-time) Att.